# How do you trace a service record during WW2 in South Africa?

Tags: south-africa

I'm looking to trace a few of my family who where on active duty during the second world war.

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't rather ask this over on the Genealogy stack? http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/ . This stack is really a lot better with famous people (and/or events).